# switch "transfer of control bypasses initialization of:" when calling a function

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

I get a "transfer of control bypasses initialization of:" error when i try to build the following switch:

```
switch (retrycancel)
{
    case 4:    //The user pressed RETRY
        //Enumerate all visible windows and store handle and caption in "windows"
        std::vector<MainHandles::window_data> windows = MainHandles().enum_windows().get_results(); 
        break;

    case 2: 
        //code
}
```

It has something to do with my calling my enumerate function. If it is not allowed to call a function from within a switch, is there a workaround for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

section 6.6.4 of the C++ standard:

> The goto statement unconditionally
>   transfers control to the statement
>   labeled by the identifier. The
>   identifier shall be a label (6.1)
>   located in the current function.

section 6.7 of the C++ standard:

> It is possible to transfer into a
>   block, but **not in a way that bypasses
>   declarations with initialization**. A
>   program that jumps from a point
>   where a local variable with automatic
>   storage duration is not in scope to a
>   point where it is in scope is
>   ill-formed unless the variable has POD
>   type (3.9) and is declared without an
>   initializer

**Emphasis** added by me. Since `switch` is really `goto` in disguise, you're encountering this behavior. To solve this, add braces if you must use a `switch`

```
switch (retrycancel)
    {
    case 4:
    {
        const std::vector<MainHandles::window_data> windows(
            MainHandles().enum_windows().get_results()
        );
        break;
    }
    case 2: 
        //code
    }
```

or refactor into `if`/`else`

```
if (retrycancel == 4) {
    const std::vector<MainHandles::window_data> windows(
        MainHandles().enum_windows().get_results()
    );
} else if (retrycancel == 2)
    // code
} else {
    ...
}
```

Though it's not obvious to me what you're hoping to accomplish with creating the `windows` `vector` inside a `switch`, so you may want to rethink your design. **Note** I added a `const` qualifier to `windows` since it's not modified in your example.

Comment: Thank you to for your answer, It was a bit late yesterday so I copied the wrong function call into the switch, the "real" one makes more sense ;-) . Nevertheless I'll go with the suggested else if loop. What is the official source of the c++ standard you quoted?

Comment: @Lumpi the ISO C++ standard, I purchased a copy some time ago.

Comment: @SamMiller : Can you please explain in simpler terms why braces is required in certain switch cases. I was creating a new object in one of the switch case and I got compiler error however if I declare or initialize a normal variable say int. I do not get any error.

Comment: Technically if and else are also goto in disguise. Or for that mater all control statements are goto in disguise (as they turn to jmp in assembly) .But, since you are using braces, it has the same effect of placing braces around the case statements.

Answer (score 18):

a switch is essentially a `goto`, that is, it is a `goto` to the appropriate label. The C++ standard forbids a goto to bypass an initialization of a non-POD object. Take the vector declaration into braces and it will solve the problem

```
switch (retrycancel)
    {
     case 4:                //The user pressed RETRY
     {
        std::vector<MainHandles::window_data> windows = MainHandles().enum_windows().get_results(); //Enumerate all visible windows and store handle and caption in "windows"
        break;
     }
    case 2: 
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! As you mentioned, it is a goto and as I'm trying to learn some proper programming I think I'll go with the if else if block suggested by Sam Miller.