# error: "transfer of control bypasses initialization of:" in switch case

Tags: c++

I am getting compilation time error in my switch case, something like : "transfer of control bypasses initialization of:". I looked into this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136295/switch-transfer-of-control-bypasses-initialization-of-when-calling-a-function) and understood that I need to put braces in order to fix the bug. But I could not understand why this bug comes in the first place. Generally I don't put braces in switch cases.

```
case 6:
        int y = 0; // adding this line alone does not give any error
        Mystack s1; // as soon as I create an instance of class
                    //I start getting squiggly under the switch 
        break;
```

P.S: Bug fixes after putting the code in braces. Please let me know why so?

Duplicate Tag: From the link I mentioned above I understood that we need to use braces to fix the bug but because the answers over there were more of advanced level and since I don't have idea about C++ standards I am not able to understand the solution mentioned. For example I have never heard of something like POD object or statement like **section 6.6.4 of the C++ standard** or **section 6.7 of the C++ standard:**  And I could not understand what this line means **A program that jumps from a point where a local variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has POD type (3.9) and is declared without an initializer.** Please explain what this line means.

Comment: The answer you linked to explains *exactly* why you get the error.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt : I have already mentioned that link in my question.

Comment: I understood how to fix the bug but I am not able to understand why and how it fixes the bug.

Comment: I already read that link and still had doubt but I cannot comment there since I don't have 50 reputation and in here SO users are giving negative votes. Nice.. Hoping till my all reputation vanishes I get an answer for what its worth.

Comment: I do not believe the accepted answer explains the why part of issue well enough for someone new. Quoting the standard is not really helpful for a person new to c++.

Comment: Since this has been closed, I'll settle for a very short explanation: If you attempt to use `s1` in the "next" case, you won't get a "not declared in this scope" error. `s1`'s lifetime lasts until the end of its scope, which is the end brace of the `switch` construct, not the `break`. If you didn't take the `6` case, an uninitialised object would be available in the following cases - and subsequently destroyed - which is no good.

Comment: And by putting the braces I limit its scope. I think I got your point. Thanks!